# How to initialize SpringContext once and share across tasks?

Tags: spring, apache-spark, spring-bean, spring-config

I am trying to initialize spring context in my Spark application. I want the context in my slave nodes as well as I want to re-use the beans. Here is the code for the same:-

```
shipperRD2.foreach(shipper->{

 AmazonS3 amazonS3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
                    FileSystemXmlApplicationContext context2 = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/spring-configuration/app-context.xml");

PersistenceWrapper persistenceWrapper = context.getBean(PersistenceWrapper.class);
});
```

However, this is leading to context refresh every time a new task runs on the slave node. Is there any way to avoid this behavior. basically, just initialize the context on the first task run, and re-use that context in the subsequent tasks.

Comment: Have you tried a singleton (anti)pattern or using broadcast variable?

Comment: Will try singleton pattern. Broadcast variable should be serializable, so won't be applicable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Jacek, I tried the singleton pattern and it worked.

```
public class SpringInit {

    private static FileSystemXmlApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(fileName);

    private SpringInit(){
    }

    public static FileSystemXmlApplicationContext getInstance(){
        return context;
    }
 }
```

From the spark,

```
shipperRD2.foreach(shipper->{

  FileSystemXmlApplicationContext context = SpringInit.getInstance();
PersistenceWrapper persistenceWrapper = context.getBean(PersistenceWrapper.class);
});
```